Differential signs in schematic in a DC_DC convertor on FB and VSNS- pin
I'm working on a DC-DC convertor Buck architecture as follows (PTPS548A28RWWR):

I noticed something interesting: there are differential symbols on the FB and VSNS- pins as follows and they have also used Nettie:

I am trying to understand the purpose of these differential symbols and Nettie and how to effectively implement this differential feature in the PCB layout. Could you please provide insights on the reason for this design choice and guidance on its application?

VSNS is the negative half of the differential pair used to sense voltage, so the reason the schematic marks it as differential is that it is differential. What is it that you're confused about? What a differential signal is? How that specific pin works? Something else? Try and ask a more specific question or explain what you're confused about.

@user1850479 I'm confused about how should I implement this deferential routing in the PCB ? should I consider length matching for these two tracks? or what?

The datasheet has recommendations on how to route the lines, follow those.  As for length matching, your switching frequency is kilohertz, so your allowable skew is probably meters, but you want to keep the differential pair tightly coupled, so you'll end up matched to within picoseconds anyway.
